# ImageView doesn't change to rounded shape

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to make my the ImageView rounded and I already created a custom IBDesignable class

Code

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class MyImageView: UIImageView {
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine already, but why is the image didn't change to rounded?

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Set the `clipToBounds` property of `UIImageView` to true.

```
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            self.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some real working code? so that I could accept the answer if it does work

Comment: just set the clipToBounds property of imageView in Storyboard.